# EAR file build by Jenkins is 1.1GB where as in hudson it is 50MB. Whats causing difference?

Tags: jenkins

EAR file builds by Jenkins is 1.1GB whereas in Hudson it is 50MB. What's causing the difference?"

Comment: What kind of package tool are you using? Maven, ant?

Comment: Did you `jar -tvf you-ear.ear` and compare the two artifacts? You area asking about the artifact size, correct?

Comment: I'm using maven and have some ant configurations.

Comment: I have mulitiple war files in the EAR file. EAR has one lib folder and each individual war has lib folder. The .jar files being downloaded in both the lib folders which is causing the size issues. What should I do to download jar files in the main lib folder?